# How to turn off CircularProgressIndicator flutter

Tags: flutter

There is a list that displays data from the database that comes to it at the time the data is fetched and until the data appears, the CircularProgressIndicator () appears so that the user knows that there is a process happening in the background.

Excellent but there is a problem with this CircularProgressIndicator () continues to work non-stop if there is no data in the database. Herein lies the problem.
It is supposed to work for a specified time and if there is no data in the database it will stop working and disappear.
Is there a way to do this? So that if there is no data that can be fetched it stops working?

My code:

```
class MainListView extends StatefulWidget {

  MainListViewState createState() => MainListViewState();

}

class MainListViewState extends State {

  final String apiURL = 'http://====================/getStudentInfo.php';

  Future<List<Studentdata>> fetchStudents() async {

    var response = await http.get(apiURL);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<Studentdata> studentList = items.map<Studentdata>((json) {
        return Studentdata.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return studentList;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data from Server.');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Studentdata>>(
      future: fetchStudents(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        );

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data
              .map((data) => Column(children: <Widget>[
            GestureDetector(

              child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [

                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 5, 0, 5),
                        child: Text(data.studentName,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left))

                  ]),),

            Divider(color: Colors.black),
          ],))
              .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below lines

```
           return FutureBuilder<List<Studentdata>>(
              future: fetchStudents(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data
                        .map((data) =>
                        Column(children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment
                                    .start,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          20, 5, 0, 5),
                                      child: Text(data.studentName,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 21),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left))

                                ]),),

                          Divider(color: Colors.black),
                        ],))
                        .toList(),
                  );
                }
                else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("No data Available");
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                }
                return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                );
              },
            );
```

Comment: this will not works cos when code hits first time it will return no data available instead of progress indicator cos u have to wait for api to fetch data and then check for return

Answer (score -1):

You can also set a value to CircularProgressIndicator() to stop at full circle indicator.

Answer (score -1):

**Just do this:**

```
if (!snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("No data Found"),
          );
        } else {
          // do something here
        }
```

It means that if status code is 200 and there is no data then you are going to get an error.